# Is returning home on a different way a sunna for jum3a

Tags: salat, sunnah, jumuah

On Eid, it's recommended not to return at home using the same way you used to go to prayer. 
I want to know if this sunna applies to the prayer of jum3a

Answer (score 1):

I found one reference that claims it's the sunna.  They begin in the context of Eid:

> It is a sunna to return on a different path (b: and likewise for Friday).
>   <sub>*An introduction to Zad al-Mustaqni'* ([link](http://hasbunallah.com.au/an-introduction-to-zaad-al-mustaqni/))</sub>

This is by *The great Hanbali scholar Imam Muwaffiq Al-Din Ibn Qudammah Al-Maqdisi*, and here "b:" indicates "notes from [Al-Bahuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Bah%C5%ABt%C4%AB), taken from Al-Raudh Al-Murbi`".

No evidence was given (in the linked version) to support this claim.

Comment: Thanks! I have searched and asked many persons but out of that, it appears not to be a sunna.